# mongoose nested populate for self referencing model after 3/4 level

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

Always find that mongoose is not populating after level 3.
tried this with mongoose@^4.12.4

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config')
var Promise = require('bluebird')
mongoose.Promise = Promise
mongoose.connect(config.dbURL, config.mongo.options)
var NodeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  friend: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Node'
  },
  name: String
});
var autoPopulateChildren = function(next) {
  this.populate('friend');
  next();
};
NodeSchema
  .pre('findOne', autoPopulateChildren)
  .pre('find', autoPopulateChildren)
var Node = mongoose.model('Node', NodeSchema)
var user1 = new Node({
  name: 'A'
})
var user2 = new Node({
  name: 'B'
})
var user3 = new Node({
  name: 'C'
})
var user4 = new Node({
  name: 'D'
})
var user5 = new Node({
  name: 'E'
})
user1.friend = user2._id
user2.friend = user3._id
user3.friend = user4._id
user4.friend = user5._id

Node.remove({})
  .then(Promise.all([user5, user4, user3, user2, user1].map(p => p.save())))
  .then(_ => Node.findOne({
    name: 'A'
  }))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

got following..
**A-->B-->C-->Object**

but expected following..
**A-->B-->C-->D-->E**

Please help!..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? Hope it will work

```
user1.friend = user2
user2.friend = user3
user3.friend = user4
user4.friend = user5

Node.remove({})
  .then(Promise.all([user5.save(), user4.save(), user3.save(), user2.save(), user1.save()]))
  .then(() => Node.findOne({
      name: 'A'
   }))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```